# Do I need a persistence.xml on my test/resources?

Tags: maven, jpa, integration-testing

I've developed some Web Services that add and modify records on a database. I'm using `Maven`.
The connection to the database is defined as a data source in the Application Server (`weblogic`). So I only have my `persistence.xml` making reference to the data source.

Now I want to do some integration tests. I need to interact with the database on these integration tests, but since these tests run outside the container, do I need to define another `persistence.xml` on my test resources path so I can get an `EntityManager` and interact with the data base? Is there another approach?

Comment: I assume you are planning on injecting all your dependencies manually, in which case you're going to call `Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory` at some point. The method will allow you to override all the required properties of the persistence unit. That being said, I fail to see how this is better than having a separate `persistence.xml` for testing. Could you please explain why you think two `persistence.xml` files is a bad idea?

Comment: Which test framework is used?

Comment: @crizzis Just wanted to see if this is the common approach. I don't think it is a bad idea. Thanks for answering.

Comment: @jklee I'm using JUnit.

Comment: @crizzis if you have a second `persistence.xml` in the test resources, then at least in Hibernate, your annotated classes are not automatically discovered, and need to be listed with `class` tags. That's because they are not part of the same classloader path. If instead of annotations you are using the `mapping-file` instead, then you might avoid that problem.

Comment: @coladict The annotated classes are not automatically discovered not because they are not part of the same classloader path, but because you typically run the tests out of the container (which is also the case for this question). This implies *Java SE* environment. As a matter of fact, Hibernate is one of the few persistence providers that *actually supports* entity autodetection in *Java SE* (via the `hibernate.archive.autodetection` property).

Comment: @crizzis Well I spoke from experience when I said it having a `persistence.xml` in a different level of the classpath does not work for Hibernate. It's controlled by `org.hibernate.boot.archive.scan.internal.StandardScanOptions` where with my settings all three booleans are true, and it did not discover any of the classes when loading from `src/test/resources/META-INF/persistence.xml` unless they were explicitly listed.

Comment: @coladict Sorry, my bad. I didn't realize Maven would put `src/test/resources/META-INF/persistence.xml` under `target/test-classes` instead of simply overriding the default resources from `src/main/resources`. This indeed changes the persistence unit root to `test-classes/` (were there any entities in `src/test/resources`, they would probably get picked up by Hibernate). The only workaround, it seems, is to extract the entities into a separate Maven module and use `<jar-file>` instead of `<classes>` in `pom.xml`. In any case, this is still not portable due to `Java SE` environment.

Answer (score 0):

The question is, how do you do your bootstrapping for database test? Only JUnit is quite elaborate.

I prefer [DeltaSpikes Test-Control Module](http://deltaspike.apache.org/documentation/test-control.html). Very fast tests, without a application server, but with CDI as container. Can also go without test persistance.xml. [Example](https://github.com/os890/ee6-ds-demo)

A other solution is [arquillian](http://arquillian.org/guides/testing_java_persistence/). Boot a complete application server, you don't need a persistance.xml on test/resources